# What's the condition that the hook: "beforeRouteEnter" in vue component will be triggered?

Tags: vuejs2, hook, vue-router

i am new to Vue.js, and encountered a few issues when learn navigation guard hooks. 
i set the component hook:'beforeRouteEnter' for Foo component and Home component. when browser go to '/', it will redirect to '/home', and Foo is Home's default child component, so it will be rendered, and the foo component hook is triggered. i am aware of all above, and what i wanna know are:

- when route change from '/home' to '/home/foo', the foo component is
  re-used indeed, why the hook for Foo component will be triggered?
- when route change from '/home/foo' to '/home', the hook for Foo
  component will be triggered, but home component is re-used too, why
  the hook for Home component is not triggered?

please refer to [fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/YangLiu/ua06n6nt/).

```
<!-- html-->    
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router"></script>
    <div id="demo">
      <router-link to="/home">Home</router-link>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>

//JS    
const Home = {
        template: `
      <div>
        <p>I am home component</p>
        <router-link to="/home/foo">Foo</router-link>
        <router-view></router-view>
      </div>
      `,
      beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
        alert('enter home component from ' + from.path + ' to ' + to.path)
        next()
      }
    }
    const Foo = {
        template: `
      <div>
        <p>I am foo component</p>
      </div>
      `,
      beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
        alert('enter foo component from ' + from.path + ' to ' + to.path)
        next()
      }
    }

    const routes = [
        {
        path: '/',
        redirect: '/home'
      },
      {
        path: '/home',
        component: Home,
        children: [
            {
            path: 'foo',
            component: Foo
          },
          {
            path: '',
            component: Foo
          }
        ]
      }
    ]

    const router = new VueRouter({
        routes
    })

    new Vue({
        el: "#demo",
      router
    })
```